# Why does measurability matter for this stochastic process?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Let $\{X_t : t \in [0,\infty)\}$ be a stochastic process. I'm studying a proof of the following result:

> If (1) $X_t$ is independent of $X_s$ for all $s\neq t$; (2) the distribution of
> $X_t$ does not depend on $t$; and (3) $E[X_1] = 0$; then $X_t = 0$
> almost surely.

My question is not about the result but rather one step in the proof where we have a set of the form $E = \{t \geq 0 : X_t \geq a\}$ and then show this set is not Lebesgue measurable. My question is why do we care that this isn't measurable? It seems really reasonable to me to have a white noise process like $\{X_t : t \in T\}$ where the $X_t$ are all iid $N(0,1)$ for example. This does mean the function $t \mapsto X_t(\omega)$ is not measurable right? So is the issue that we can't talk about integrating sample paths and things like that? Thanks!

Comment: I suspect this is a matter of definition.  How does the source of this proof define "stochastic process"?